# How much can a wave function tell us?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, probability, born-rule

We can not predict the future by getting the velocity and position of particles since it’s not possible to get both of these together due to the uncertainty principle. But, according to Hawking’s book brief answers to the big questions, we can use the wave function of a particle to predict what the wave function will look like in the future. My question is, how much information can we get from these wave functions (in terms of the future?)? I would think that we can’t predict the exact future, but maybe probabilities if what would happen?

Comment: Yes wave functions can give probability distributions, that determine how much information we can get. Yes, we can't predict the future.

Comment: The uncertainty principle shows limits of information attainable. So how much info you can get also depends on how much information you give up. An example could be given for specific cases.

Comment: And have much information you have can of course help you figure likely events are to occur.

Comment: Hawking? Which book? Which page?

Comment: @Qmechanic Yeah, his book is called brief answers to the big questions.

Comment: The future IS to some extent predictable, not entirely, but to a useful extent. I don't believe wave functions are any help in predicting the future of the macroscopic world we see around us within our lifetime, but if you could offer a real-life example which proves me wrong, you might convert me.

Comment: @Qmechanic my book is in Swedish but chapter 4 of brief answers to the big questions is called “can we predict the future” and in my book he talks about this around page 100. (Not a specific page) Also, I may have misinterpreted what he wrote, but I think he says that we can’t predict exactly how a particle will act in the future, because we can’t know position and velocity simultaneously, but we can predict combinations of them in the form of wave functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wave function for a system tells you “the probabilities for the possible results of measurements made on the system” ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function)). I would have strengthened this statement to say “all possible measurements”.

Probabilistic predictions are the best we can do since the world obeys quantum mechanics, not classical mechanics. The wave function describes the complete quantum state of a system and how it is evolving in time, replacing classical concepts such as particle trajectories.

Comment: If the world obeys quantum mechanics, why couldn't our politicians use a wave function to predict the outcome of some of the crazy decisions they make, even if it's only a probable outcome? You would be performing a great service to the nation if you told them how to do it..

Comment: @MichaelWalsby Because the number of possibilities would be impossible to calculate fast enough to get meaningful estimates at all.  We already have enough trouble accurately predicting weather; using wave functions to predict everything would be orders of magnitude worse.